# brew search generates mail notification "You recently used a password to access an endpoint through the GitHub API using Homebrew/2.2.2"

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew, git

I got a mail from GitHub:

> You recently used a password to access an endpoint through the GitHub
>   API using Homebrew/2.2.2 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15.2)
>   curl/7.64.1. We will deprecate basic authentication using password to
>   this endpoint soon:
>
> https://api.github.com/search/code?q=user%3AHomebrew+path%3AFormula+path%3ACasks+path%3A.+filename%3Abusybox+extension%3Arb&per_page=100
>
> We recommend using a personal access token (PAT) with the appropriate
>   scope to access this endpoint instead. Visit
>   https://github.com/settings/tokens for more information.
>
> Thanks, The GitHub Team

The mail came after I searched for formula:

```
~ brew search test
Warning: Cask 'sqleo' is unreadable: undefined method `method_missing_message' for Utils:Module
Warning: Cask 'squirrelsql' is unreadable: undefined method `method_missing_message' for Utils:Module
Warning: Cask 'yiddish-klal' is unreadable: undefined method `method_missing_message' for Utils:Module
==> Formulae
cpptest                      cxxtest                      memtester                    phoronix-test-suite          slowhttptest                 testdisk                     unittest                     vttest
cpputest                     git-test                     minetest                     shelltestrunner              speedtest-cli                testssl                      unittest-cpp

==> Casks
aja-system-test                                colortester                                    emacs-pretest                                  nsregextester                                  sqlitestudio
clementine-latest                              eclipse-testing                                latest                                         socket-io-tester                               synology-note-station-client
```

Always a prompt like this pops up:

[image]

It look like I have some kind of misconfiguration? I don't like that `brew` uses my GitHub credentials.

Comment: Did you see [Homebrew installation requests to use my confidential keychain information. Should I allow it to do so?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280131/homebrew-installation-requests-to-use-my-confidential-keychain-information-shou)

Comment: I also received, do i need to take action? Where can i find more information to set this up correctly?!

Comment: There’s is no misconfiguration and this is intended / by design if you run brew on a system where you have stored your GH  keys. Your shell/git is what provides the keys to anything that runs, (which includes brew)

Comment: Great question +1 a lot of people are going to learn from your clearly documented and easily overlooked power of integration of command line tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't like that brew uses my GitHub credentials.

**Brew is not using your GitHub credentials, you are.**

Brew is just an exceptionally advanced scripting engine that allows you to download and build *from source* software that’s found on GitHub, Sourceforge, et al.  It’s important to note that you’re not downloading from Brew, but a Brew is automating *your* download of the software.

**What steps did you take to save git keys in your shell environment?**

You would reverse that to have brew not be granted access to your keys when it calls git or makes web / API calls.

- https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: It’s not a problem as brew doesn’t have your credentials.  If you didn’t have a GitHub login, at some point it would throw an error that you had too many accesses (I don’t remember the error message) and you should get a token.  Your being told to get the token because they’re no longer using *basic authentication*.  Get a token.